# How much wood will this woodchuck chuck?

Tags: actionscript-3

Does this code make sense? I did not write it but was given it as a question I need some help as to what the answer is if there even is one, thanks in advance.

```
for (var i : int = 0;  i <10; i++) {
    woodchuck.chuck(wood);
    if(i%2){
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It makes sense.

Here what this code is going to do:

1. instatiate `i` variable and assign value 0 to it (first statements in `for` loop)
2. execute `woodchuck.cuck(wood);`
3. if `i` modulo 2 (`i % 2`) gives different value than 0, then it will increment `i` (`0` is interpreted as `false` in most programming languages)
4. increment `i`, checks if it is smaller than 10, and goes to step 2

So what you have is:

```
i   | woodchuck  | source of `i` increment
0   |    1       |    initialization
1   |    2       |    `for` statement
2   |    2       |    `if` statement
3   |    3       |    `for` statement
4   |    3       |    `if` statement
5   |    4       |    `for` statement
6   |    4       |    `if` statement
7   |    5       |    `for` statement
8   |    5       |    `if` statement
9   |    6       |    `for` statement
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer did not make sense to me so I'm answering this again just in case you didn't understand it. I do not know this programming launguage for sure, but it looks kind of like JavaScript which I understand a little of.

So the first time, when it begins the loop, variable i is set to zero. Woodchuck.chuck() is called, and since 0 is not divisible by two, it skipps that extra if statement and runs through the loop again as one.

One is still less than ten, so `Woodchuck.chuck()` is run again, and i increases to 2 since it is still not divisible by it.

This is where it gets interesting. This time, since two IS divisible by itself, after chucking the wood, i increases by TWO which makes it four. This process repeats until I is ten, where it no longer fits inside the parameters, stopping the for loop.

Thus, `Woodchuck.chuck(wood)` is run a total of six times:

```
-when i is 0
-when i is 1
-when i is 2
-when i is 4
-when i is 6 
-when i is 8
```

Hope that helps and I didn't mess anything up.